# ASP Include over HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, file-io, https

I have a payment page that I am using https on.  The page has the following include statement

```
<% Response.WriteFile("/Includes/header.asp"); %>
```

Chrome and IE are blocking the js and css files in this include because they are unsecure.  These js and css files have relative urls.  Is there any way to specifiy the include as https or do I need to change the relative file paths to use a fully resolved https urls?

Comment: Show us the generated source.

Comment: I have never seen the `Response.WriteFile` function in Classic ASP and it is not listed in the reference for the [`Response`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525405%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) object. What am I missing here?

Comment: If this doesn't generate error it means you're using ASP.NET and not classic ASP. Please tag properly in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Response.Writefile is used in asp.net but not in classic

Classic ASP uses the same syntax as SSI eg

```
<!-- #include file ="pathto/header.inc" -->

<!-- #include virtual ="/pathfromroot/header.inc" -->
```

If your page isn't picking up js or css files then maybe you need to copy them to the same secure environment as the payment page itself.  I've worked on worldpay and paypoint integrations and they both have the facility to upload files